# How to reload only one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 3 columns and the column values keeps on changing dynamically from database.
All rows have refresh button at last column.

What should happen when I click the refresh button is that only that particular row should get refreshed.

But that's not what is happening. When I click on the first row refresh button it refreshes and shows an alert value, but when I click the other refresh buttons of table except the first row it they do not not get refreshed. They do not even show a value in an alert.

Here is code I have used:

ajax,JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id;

    function refreshRecord(value) {
        id = value;
        alert("id is " + id);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(this).("#refresh").click(function() {
            var fileId = id;
            alert("ajax id is " + id);
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "checkStatusAndNumRecs",
                data: {
                    fileId: fileId
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#div1").html(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $("#div1").html("It was a failure !!!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

html code

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="refreshRecord(this.value)" id="refresh">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="refreshRecord(this.value)" id="refresh">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="refreshRecord(this.value)" id="refresh">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="refreshRecord(this.value)" id="refresh">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I see no buttons in your code and no element with the id `#refresh`. Please expand your code with all related parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple radio buttons with the same id. That is invalid html. Use a class instead like

```
<input type="radio" name="submit" ... class="refresh">
```

and change your javascript to

```
$("input.refresh").click(function() {
```

Further you should not use the two different `onclick` events for the same event (I am not even sure they will be in the correct order, could be random.)

You can remove `onclick="refreshRecord(this.value)"` from your html and the `refreshRecord` function from your javascript and replace `id` with `this.value` in `$("input.refresh").click(function() { ... })`.

Comment: Thanks Raidri, and how to use if in case of i am using <a href class="refresh"></a> instead of input type?

Comment: Replace `$("input.refresh")` with `$("a.refresh")`. What you also still have to do, is putting the id / fileid of the row in the refresh button / link, so that you have the id for your ajax call. In the first code you had the same value `submit` on all buttons. If you use links, put an data attribute in them like `data-fileid="1"` and use `var fileId = $(this).data('fileid');` in the ajax call.